# Big Query - Table 'Copy' from Console Not working, But the same works fine from bq CLI

Tags: google-bigquery

Across project level when trying to Copying the tables in big query, it works fine using bq CLI but not from Console.

Big Query --> Project:Dataset.tableXYZ --> Open --> 'Copy' --> provide_destination_table_name --> 'Copy'

it keeps running forever.

The same works fine from  bq command!

````
ksiva@DESKTOP-K361VKU:~$ bq cp databerries:targeting.ksiva_test_display_creatives_300x250Targeting databerries:targeting.ksiva_test_display_creatives_300x250Targeting_copy
Waiting on bqjob_r204fd137b63ee21f_00000180605848fc_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
Table 'databerries:targeting.ksiva_test_display_creatives_300x250Targeting' successfully copied to 'databerries:targeting.ksiva_test_display_creatives_300x250Targeting_copy'
ksiva@DESKTOP-K361VKU:~$```
````

Comment: There was an issue with this in the UI you can add a comment at the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/230236388) and click on the `+1` button to indicate that this is also happening to you.This is now fixed but it can take some days for you to see the changes.If at the moment this is not fixed for your project, you can click on the button `DISABLE EDITOR TABS` and this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is an issue with UI indeed and it seems to be started working now.

Comment: @KartCraze It is a good practice to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if the issue was confirmed to be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! Yes it was an issue with google console indeed and it seems to be started working now.